# How to run jQuery fadeIn() and slideDown() simultaneously?

Tags: jquery

I've got a div with display: none;
Now I want to show it using both: fadeIn and slideDown simultaneously.

```
$(this).slideDown({duration: 'slow', queue: false});
$(this).fadeIn({duration: 'slow', queue: false});
```

The div is selected properly. But when I trigger the effect, all it does is the slideDown. And if I just delete the slideDown I can see the fadeIn, so there is nothing wrong with the syntax.
But why doesn't it trigger both animations?

Comment: I've been trying to work this out for a bit.  I haven't got the 'right' answer but this may help you: $('bla').slideDown basically maps to this in the source: $('bla').animate({ height: 'show', paddingTop: 'show', paddingBottom: 'show', marginTop: 'show', marginBottom: 'show' }.  So you can put that and animate will act just like a slideDown.

Comment: @iWebaholic: please select the correct anser

Comment: Please select @pbierre 's answer as the accepted answer.  Good solution.

Answer (score 159):

Use `animate()` instead of `fadeIn()`:

```
$(this)
  .css('opacity', 0)
  .slideDown('slow')
  .animate(
    { opacity: 1 },
    { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
  );
```

Comment: This answer should be selected as the correct one! Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Yup... this is the right answer. However, I prefer "fast" over "slow" animation, as even little delays in UI responsiveness can irritate users.

Comment: Perhaps more of an explanation as to why they cannot both be run at once?  Not sure why this hasn't been chosen as the correct answer yet however.

Comment: Really nice solution. Should be selected as correct.

Answer (score 5):

start with `height:0px` and `opacity:0; filter: alpha(opacity = 0)` then on the action do:

```
$(this).stop().animate({
    height: 200,
    opacity: 1
}, 350);
```

Change the height (i set to 200) and the duration (i set to 350) to whatever you want.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution, you can use it as a jQuery plugin.

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    // Sort us out with the options parameters
    var getAnimOpts = function (a, b, c) {
            if (!a) { return {duration: 'normal'}; }
            if (!!c) { return {duration: a, easing: b, complete: c}; }
            if (!!b) { return {duration: a, complete: b}; }
            if (typeof a === 'object') { return a; }
            return { duration: a };
        },
        getUnqueuedOpts = function (opts) {
            return {
                queue: false,
                duration: opts.duration,
                easing: opts.easing
            };
        };
    // Declare our new effects
    $.fn.showDown = function (a, b, c) {
        var slideOpts = getAnimOpts(a, b, c), fadeOpts = getUnqueuedOpts(slideOpts);
        $(this).hide().css('opacity', 0).slideDown(slideOpts).animate({ opacity: 1 }, fadeOpts);
    };
    $.fn.hideUp = function (a, b, c) {
        var slideOpts = getAnimOpts(a, b, c), fadeOpts = getUnqueuedOpts(slideOpts);
        $(this).show().css('opacity', 1).slideUp(slideOpts).animate({ opacity: 0 }, fadeOpts);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Now you can use it the same way you would use jQuery’s .fadeIn (or fadeOut) effect.

```
// Show
$('.alert').showDown('slow');
// Hide
$('.alert').hideUp('fast', function() {
    // Animation complete: '.alert' is now hidden
});
```

This will resize our element’s height with a fading effect.

It was [originally posted on my blog](http://webmaestro.fr/blog/fade-a-bit-more-nicely-with-showdown-and-hideup/).

Comment: +1 very nice. I removed the `.css('opacity', 0)` and `.css('opacity', 1)` because when I wanted to `hideUp` while the object was still `showDown`ing the opacity would go straight to 1 before it tries to hide.

Comment: I think both functions should `return $(this)...` to allow method chaining.

Answer (score 4):

```js
$('.target')                    
    .hide()  
    .slideDown(500, 'swing')  
    .css('opacity', 0)  
    .animate({opacity: 1}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});
```

Comment: Your answer will be better if you explain the code and how it solves the question

Answer (score 3):

The more modern solution is to use values of `'show'` and `'hide'` when you want to combine animations:

```js
$('.show').on('click', function () {
  $('.example').animate({
    opacity: 'show',
    height: 'show',
    marginTop: 'show',
    marginBottom: 'show',
    paddingTop: 'show',
    paddingBottom: 'show'
  })
})
$('.hide').on('click', function () {
  $('.example').animate({
    opacity: 'hide',
    height: 'hide',
    marginTop: 'hide',
    marginBottom: 'hide',
    paddingTop: 'hide',
    paddingBottom: 'hide'
  })
})
```

```css
.example {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button type="button" class="show">Show</button>
  <button type="button" class="hide">Hide</button>
</p>
<div class="example"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! I've added `, "slow" ` to the end of the curly bracket to make it smoother.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").bind("click", function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $('#slidedown').slideDown("slow");
        }, 500);
        $("#content").fadeOut(500);
        $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": "1" }, "slow");
        });
    });
```

this is for fade out but i think it's what your after.  please have a look at the example too: http://jsfiddle.net/oddacon/M44md/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible now to use CSS3 transitions. It allows to achieve very flexible solutions.

HTML

```
<div id="btn">Click me</div>
<div id="hidden"></div>
```

CSS

```
#hidden {
    display: none; opacity: 0; height: 100px; background: red;
    transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
#hidden.opened {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var div = $('#hidden');
    if ( ! div.is(':animated')) {
        div.slideToggle(600).toggleClass('opened');
    }
});
```