# How to use fadein() and slideDown() with together?

Tags: jquery, mouseover

How to use fadein()  and slideDown() with together ?

.....................................................................................................................................................................

```
$('#login-trigger, #login-box').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'login-trigger') $('#login-box').fadeIn('slow');
        if (e.target.id == 'login-trigger') $('#login-box').slideDown('slow');  
        clearTimeout( $('#login-box').data('timer') );
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('#login-box').data('timer', 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#login-box').fadeOut('slow')
                $('#login-box').slideUp('slow')
            }, 300)
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run jQuery fadeIn() and slideDown() simultaneously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524612/how-to-run-jquery-fadein-and-slidedown-simultaneously)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(your selector).animate({ height: 0, opacity: 0 }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle for the height and opacity, since **mouseleave** works after **mouseenter**

```
$("#login-box").animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'slow');
```

Also I suggest you to add e.preventDefault(); after the mouseenter, mouseleave function execution.

```
$('#login-trigger, #login-box').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'login-trigger') $("#login-box").animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'slow');
        clearTimeout( $('#login-box').data('timer') );
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    mouseleave: function(e) {
        $('#login-box').data('timer', 
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#login-box").animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'slow');
        }, 300)
        );
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```