# Why this effect only works the first time only?

Tags: jquery

I found here on stackoverflow this useful piece of code, but for some reason it only works on the first time it is applied and never again....

How can I make the animation work always and not only the 1st time?

Source: [How to run jQuery fadeIn() and slideDown() simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524612/how-to-run-jquery-fadein-and-slidedown-simultaneously)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  var something3 = document.getElementById('nav-action');

  something3.style.cursor = 'pointer';

  something3.onclick = function() {

    $(".menu-item")
      .css('opacity', 0)
      .slideDown('slow')
      .animate(
        { opacity: 1 },
        { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
      );

  });
```

This is my CSS

```
.menu-item {
  font-size: 61px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin-top: 12px;  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px; opacity:0;
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it was only working once was because the `.slideDown()` method would set the `display` of the element to `block`, and then on every other click you were only animating the opacity. You could chain the `.hide()` method in order to hide the element before animating it.

In doing so, it will work multiple times:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/su2q65gp/)

```
$(".menu-item")
  .hide()
  .css('opacity', 0)
  .slideDown('slow')
  .animate(
    { opacity: 1 },
    { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
);
```